# Асинхронный вызов метода в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await

У меня имеется **WPF**-приложение, работающее с базой данных. Количество записей в базе довольно большое и постоянно растёт. В проекте используется **ORM**(EF 6).
Имеется некий класс, работающий непосредственно с контекстом базы данных:

```
public class Store : IStore {...}
```

В интерфейсе класса определён ряд методов, код в которых обращается непосредственно к базе через EF-контекст, соответственно, выполнение метода занимает довольно длительное время, что может вызвать простой интерфейса пользователя, если я всё правильно понимаю. Следовательно, нужно вынести операции получения данных из базы в отдельные потоки. Так, скажем, в `Store` определен метод:

```
public ICollection<Product> GetAllProducts() {...}
```

Если я правильно понимаю, мне необходимо добавить его асинхронную реализацию:

```
public async Task<ICollection<Product>> GetAllProductsAsync()
{
    return await Task<ICollection<Product>>.Factory.StartNew(GetAllProducts)
}
```

Как правильно воспользоваться таким методом в самом приложении в `ViewModel`, Скажем, чтобы, пока данные загружаются, в `StatusBar` отображался прогресс загрузки данных, а `DataGrid` отобразил результат как только данные загрузятся?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Окей, давайте начнём с `Task.Factory.StartNew`. Это нужно только если ваш запрос к базе данных не поддерживает асинхронность сам, и требует выделения отдельного потока (кстати, лучше писать просто `Task.Run`).

Для свежего Entity Framework это не так, асинхронные функции поддерживаются правильно, из коробки: [Entity Framework tutorial: async query and save](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework6/async-query-and-save.aspx).

С асинхронностью на уровне базы данных вам не нужно создавать отдельные потоки.

---

По поводу прогресса, с этим хуже. EF не поддерживает информацию о прогрессе операции, так что вы можете просто вывести состояние «читаю», и считывать до тех пор, пока не закончите.

В случае, когда/если будет имплементирована поддержка прогресса, вам можно будет воспользоваться интерфейсом `IProgress<T>`.

---

Таким образом, код в VM будет выглядеть так:

```
IsLoading = true;
var localData = await model.LoadDataAsync();
IsLoading = false;
Data = localData;
```

---

Скорее всего, вы не захотите выкладывать модельные классы для View, поэтому вам понадобится обёртка, создающая VM-объекты для ваших entity:

```
// в модели
IQueryable<TEntity> GetData();
```

```
// в VM
IsLoading = true;
var localData = new List<EntityVM>();
await model.GetData().ForEachAsync(entity => localData.Add(new EntityVM(entity));
IsLoading = false;
Data = localData;
```

Ну и, как верно отмечает @Pavel Mayorov, возможно вы захотите ловить исключения, так что вам понадобится try:

```
IsLoading = true;
var localData = new List<EntityVM>();
try
{
    await model.GetData().ForEachAsync(entity => localData.Add(new EntityVM(entity));
    Data = new ObservableCollection<EntityVM>(localData);
}
catch
{
    IsFailed = true;
    throw;
}
finally
{
    IsLoading = false;
}
```

Или, если вы хотите, чтобы данные появлялись не все вместе, а по мере подгрузки, наверное подойдёт просто

```
    await model.GetData().ForEachAsync(entity => Data.Add(new EntityVM(entity));
```

(но здесь я не уверен, т. к. ни разу не пробовал).

Comment: "По поводу прогресса, с этим хуже. EF не поддерживает информацию о прогрессе операции, так что вы можете просто вывести состояние «читаю», и считывать до тех пор, пока не закончите." - а как это будет выглядеть во VIewModel?

Comment: @klutch1991: Добавил код.

Comment: @klutch1991: Дополнил ещё.

Comment: @VladD А как будет выглядеть сигнатура метода GetData? Это и есть мой асинхронный метод?

Comment: @klutch1991: Не, GetData возвращает просто IQueryable :) В этом фокус. Что-нибудь наподобие `context.Articles.Where(a.Author == author)`. Вся асинхронность в `ForEachAsync`.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Спасибо, добавил.

Comment: @VladD, уфф... что-то я совсем запутался.. Т.е. метод ForEachAsync() можно вызвать на колеекции типа DBSet из EF-контекста?

Comment: @klutch1991: Да. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220211%28v=vs.113%29.aspx

Comment: @VladD, спасибо, хотел бы ещё уточнить, а что если операция, которую я хочу выполнить, никак не связана с базой, а просто требует длительного времени для выполнения, как правильно выполнять её в VM?

Comment: @klutch1991 если операция требует много процессорного времени или использует синхронное API - то через `Task.Run`. Но сначала лучше поискать асинхронное API для операции.

Comment: @klutch1991: Именно так, `Task.Run` — для тяжёлых по процессору операций, для остальных они сами должны предоставлять async-интерфейс.